# How do I log a Python error with debug information?

Tags: python, exception, logging, python-logging

I am printing Python exception messages to a log file with `logging.error`:

```
import logging
try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    logging.error(e)  # ERROR:root:division by zero
```

Is it possible to print more detailed information about the exception and the code that generated it than just the exception string? Things like line numbers or stack traces would be great.

Answer (score 1153, accepted):

[`logger.exception`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) will output a stack trace alongside the error message.

For example:

```
import logging
try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    logging.exception("message")
```

Output:

```
ERROR:root:message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

[@Paulo Cheque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1163081/paulo-cheque) notes, "be aware that in Python 3 you must call the `logging.exception` method just inside the `except` part. If you call this method in an arbitrary place you may get a bizarre exception. The docs alert about that."

Comment: The `exception` method simply calls `error(message, exc_info=1)`. As soon as you pass `exc_info` to any of the logging methods from an exception context, you will get a traceback.

Comment: You can also set `sys.excepthook` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8054179/326849)) to avoid having to wrap all your code in try/except.

Comment: You could just write `except Exception:` because you are not using `e` in any way ;)

Comment: You may very well want to inspect `e` when attempting to interactively debug your code. :) This is why I always include it.

Comment: This approach produce multiple lines in your log (for one event) file which is not a good practice. You can see my solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40428650/772756)

Comment: Why `except Exception as e:` when `e` is never used?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, in this case, there is no real handling of the exception and therefore it make sense to add `raise` at the end of the `except` scope. Otherwise, running will continue as if everything was fine.

Comment: @Dror - it depends. In this case, the code is literally designed to force a `ZeroDivisionError` and log it, so I mean, it's doing its job.

Comment: If you want to log the long traceback at a different log level, then do `logging.error("message"); logging.debug(e, exc_info=True)`, or whichever level you prefer.

Comment: @CivFan the exception handling is merely printing the error. Afterward, the program will continue running. If you actually need to break the run, after logging, you need to re-raise the exception.

Comment: @MarcoFerrari, additionally, a bare `except` will catch SystemExit and KeyboardInterrupt, which may not be intended. `except Exception as e` won't catch these. https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy

Comment: You can also do `logging.exception(e)` if you can't think of a good thing to pass here.

Comment: IMHO, `error(message, exc_info=1)` which is equivalent to `exception` method, is much more readable.

Answer (score 274):

Using `exc_info` options may be better, to allow you to choose the error level (if you use `exception`, it will always be at the `error` level):

```
try:
    # do something here
except Exception as e:
    logging.critical(e, exc_info=True)  # log exception info at CRITICAL log level
```

Comment: @CivFan: I didn't actually look at the other edits or the post intro; that intro was also added by a 3rd-party editor. I don't see anywhere in the deleted comments that that was ever the intention, but I may as well undo my edit and remove the comments, it is has been too long for the voting here to have been for anything other than the edited version.

Comment: Is `logging.fatal` a method in the logging library? I only see `critical`.

Comment: @Ian It's an alias to `critical`, just like `warn` is to `warning`.

Comment: If we use exc_info, is there any additional value from also logging the e?

Answer (score 220):

One nice thing about `logging.exception` that [SiggyF's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5191885) doesn't show is that you can pass in an arbitrary message, and logging will still show the full traceback with all the exception details:

```
import logging
try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    logging.exception("Deliberate divide by zero traceback")
```

With the default (in recent versions) logging behaviour of just printing errors to `sys.stderr`, it looks like this:

```
>>> import logging
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except ZeroDivisionError:
...     logging.exception("Deliberate divide by zero traceback")
... 
ERROR:root:Deliberate divide by zero traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: Can an exception be logged without providing a message?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro - I'd suggest you pass `''` if you really don't want to type a message... the function can't be called without at least one argument, though, so you'll have to give it something.

Comment: @ncoghlan can you please suggest the solution for the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68168756/python-how-to-handle-https-connection-refused-error-and-write-the-logs-in-serve

Answer (score 51):

[Quoting](https://realpython.com/blog/python/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/)

> What if your application does logging some other way – not using the `logging` module?

Now, `traceback` could be used here.

```
import traceback

def log_traceback(ex, ex_traceback=None):
    if ex_traceback is None:
        ex_traceback = ex.__traceback__
    tb_lines = [ line.rstrip('\n') for line in
                 traceback.format_exception(ex.__class__, ex, ex_traceback)]
    exception_logger.log(tb_lines)
```

- Use it in *Python 2*:

  ```
  try:
      # your function call is here
  except Exception as ex:
      _, _, ex_traceback = sys.exc_info()
      log_traceback(ex, ex_traceback)
  ```
- Use it in *Python 3*:

  ```
  try:
      x = get_number()
  except Exception as ex:
      log_traceback(ex)
  ```

Comment: Why did you place "_, _, ex_traceback = sys.exc_info()" outside the function log_traceback and then pass it as an argument? Why not use it directly inside the function?

Comment: @BasilMusa, to answer your question, in short, to compatible with Python 3, because the `ex_traceback` is from  `ex.__traceback__` under Python 3, but `ex_traceback` is from `sys.exc_info()` under Python 2.

Comment: Why not using [`traceback.format_exc()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exc) rather than `traceback.format_exception(...)`?

Answer (score 22):

You can log the stack trace without an exception.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug

> The second optional keyword argument is stack_info, which defaults to False. If true, stack information is added to the logging message, including the actual logging call. Note that this is not the same stack information as that displayed through specifying exc_info: The former is stack frames from the bottom of the stack up to the logging call in the current thread, whereas the latter is information about stack frames which have been unwound, following an exception, while searching for exception handlers.

Example:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
>>> logging.getLogger().info('This prints the stack', stack_info=True)
INFO:root:This prints the stack
Stack (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>>>
```

Answer (score 12):

If you use plain logs - all your log records should correspond this rule: `one record = one line`. Following this rule you can use `grep` and other tools to process your log files.

But traceback information is multi-line. So my answer is an extended version of solution proposed by [zangw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33211980/772756) above in this thread. The problem is that traceback lines could have `\n` inside, so we need to do an extra work to get rid of this line endings:

```
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger('your_logger_here')

def log_app_error(e: BaseException, level=logging.ERROR) -> None:
    e_traceback = traceback.format_exception(e.__class__, e, e.__traceback__)
    traceback_lines = []
    for line in [line.rstrip('\n') for line in e_traceback]:
        traceback_lines.extend(line.splitlines())
    logger.log(level, traceback_lines.__str__())
```

After that (when you'll be analyzing your logs) you could copy / paste required traceback lines from your log file and do this:

```
ex_traceback = ['line 1', 'line 2', ...]
for line in ex_traceback:
    print(line)
```

Profit!

Answer (score 11):

This answer builds up from the above excellent ones.

In most applications, you won't be calling logging.exception(e) directly. Most likely you have defined a custom logger specific for your application or module like this:

```
# Set the name of the app or module
my_logger = logging.getLogger('NEM Sequencer')
# Set the log level
my_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Let's say we want to be fancy and log to a graylog2 log server
graylog_handler = graypy.GELFHandler('some_server_ip', 12201)
graylog_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
my_logger.addHandler(graylog_handler)
```

In this case, just use the logger to call the exception(e) like this:

```
try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError, e:
    my_logger.exception(e)
```

Comment: This is a useful finish touch indeed if you want a dedicated logger just for exceptions.

Answer (score 11):

If "debugging information" means the values present when exception was raised, then `logging.exception(...)` won't help. So you'll need a tool that logs all variable values along with the traceback lines automatically.

Out of the box you'll get log like

```
2020-03-30 18:24:31 main ERROR   File "./temp.py", line 13, in get_ratio
2020-03-30 18:24:31 main ERROR     return height / width
2020-03-30 18:24:31 main ERROR       height = 300
2020-03-30 18:24:31 main ERROR       width = 0
2020-03-30 18:24:31 main ERROR builtins.ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Have a look at some pypi tools, I'd name:

- [tbvaccine](https://pypi.org/project/tbvaccine/)
- [traceback-with-variables](https://pypi.org/project/traceback-with-variables/)
- [better-exceptions](https://pypi.org/project/better-exceptions/)

Some of them give you pretty crash messages:
[image]

But you might find some more on [pypi](https://pypi.org)

Answer (score 6):

A little bit of decorator treatment (very loosely inspired by the Maybe monad and lifting). You can safely remove Python 3.6 type annotations and use an older message formatting style.

**fallible.py**

```
from functools import wraps
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, Optional
import logging


A = TypeVar('A')


def fallible(*exceptions, logger=None) \
        -> Callable[[Callable[..., A]], Callable[..., Optional[A]]]:
    """
    :param exceptions: a list of exceptions to catch
    :param logger: pass a custom logger; None means the default logger, 
                   False disables logging altogether.
    """
    def fwrap(f: Callable[..., A]) -> Callable[..., Optional[A]]:

        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            except exceptions:
                message = f'called {f} with *args={args} and **kwargs={kwargs}'
                if logger:
                    logger.exception(message)
                if logger is None:
                    logging.exception(message)
                return None

        return wrapped

    return fwrap
```

Demo:

```
In [1] from fallible import fallible

In [2]: @fallible(ArithmeticError)
    ...: def div(a, b):
    ...:     return a / b
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [3]: div(1, 2)
Out[3]: 0.5

In [4]: res = div(1, 0)
ERROR:root:called <function div at 0x10d3c6ae8> with *args=(1, 0) and **kwargs={}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/fallible.py", line 17, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-17-e056bd886b5c>", line 3, in div
    return a / b

In [5]: repr(res)
'None'
```

You can also modify this solution to return something a bit more meaningful than `None` from the `except` part (or even make the solution generic, by specifying this return value in `fallible`'s arguments).

Answer (score 5):

Since Python 3.5, it's possible to explicitly specify the exception in the logging function:

```
try:
    1/0
except Exception as ex:
    logging.error("Error occurred", exc_info = ex)
```

The `logging.exception` function still works but must be called only within the `except` block and does not allow specifying log level.

Comment: This is the best answer. It works on all log levels and also if the logging happens somewhere else, outside of the `except`-block.

Answer (score 2):

In your logging module(if custom module) just enable stack_info.

```
api_logger.exceptionLog("*Input your Custom error message*",stack_info=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [this code example](https://gist.github.com/tzaffi/cb3f1b7f238c345a6be462e922c97ba8) (which works for Python 2 and 3) you'll see the function definition below which can extract

- method
- line number
- code context
- file path

for an *entire stack trace*, whether or not there has been an exception:

```py
def sentry_friendly_trace(get_last_exception=True):
    try:
        current_call = list(map(frame_trans, traceback.extract_stack()))
        alert_frame = current_call[-4]
        before_call = current_call[:-4]

        err_type, err, tb = sys.exc_info() if get_last_exception else (None, None, None)
        after_call = [alert_frame] if err_type is None else extract_all_sentry_frames_from_exception(tb)

        return before_call + after_call, err, alert_frame
    except:
        return None, None, None
```

Of course, this function depends on the entire gist linked above, and in particular `extract_all_sentry_frames_from_exception()` and `frame_trans()` but the exception info extraction totals less than around 60 lines.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I wrap all functions around my custom designed logger:

```
import json
import timeit
import traceback
import sys
import unidecode

def main_writer(f,argument):
  try:
    f.write(str(argument))
  except UnicodeEncodeError:
    f.write(unidecode.unidecode(argument))


def logger(*argv,logfile="log.txt",singleLine = False):
  """
  Writes Logs to LogFile
  """
  with open(logfile, 'a+') as f:
    for arg in argv:
      if arg == "{}":
        continue
      if type(arg) == dict and len(arg)!=0:
        json_object = json.dumps(arg, indent=4, default=str)
        f.write(str(json_object))
        f.flush()
        """
        for key,val in arg.items():
          f.write(str(key) + " : "+ str(val))
          f.flush()
        """
      elif type(arg) == list and len(arg)!=0:
        for each in arg:
          main_writer(f,each)
          f.write("\n")
          f.flush()
      else:
        main_writer(f,arg)
        f.flush()
      if singleLine==False:
        f.write("\n")
    if singleLine==True:
      f.write("\n")

def tryFunc(func, func_name=None, *args, **kwargs):
  """
  Time for Successfull Runs
  Exception Traceback for Unsuccessful Runs
  """
  stack = traceback.extract_stack()
  filename, codeline, funcName, text = stack[-2]
  func_name = func.__name__ if func_name is None else func_name # sys._getframe().f_code.co_name # func.__name__
  start = timeit.default_timer()
  x = None
  try:
    x = func(*args, **kwargs)
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    # logger("Time to Run {} : {}".format(func_name, stop - start))
  except Exception as e:
    logger("Exception Occurred for {} :".format(func_name))
    logger("Basic Error Info :",e)
    logger("Full Error TraceBack :")
    # logger(e.message, e.args)
    logger(traceback.format_exc())
  return x

def bad_func():
  return 'a'+ 7

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger(234)
    logger([1,2,3])
    logger(['a','b','c'])
    logger({'a':7,'b':8,'c':9})
    tryFunc(bad_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to create a context manager, to log and raise Exceptions:

```py
import logging
from contextlib import AbstractContextManager


class LogError(AbstractContextManager):

    def __init__(self, logger=None):
        self.logger = logger.name if isinstance(logger, logging.Logger) else logger

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if exc_value is not None:
            logging.getLogger(self.logger).exception(exc_value)


with LogError():
    1/0
```

You can either pass a logger name or a logger instance to `LogError()`. By default it will use the base logger (by passing `None` to logging.getLogger).
One could also simply add a switch for raising the error or just logging it.

Comment: this answer is out of the question scope/.

Answer (score 0):

The best and minimal library for doing this is `loguru`, which shows an in-baked traceback and provides debug info:

```py
import sys
from loguru import logger
logger.add(sys.stdout, level="TRACE")

try:
    a = 1/0
except Exception as err:
    logger.exception(str(err), backtrace=True, diagnose=True)
```

Outputs:

```
2023-08-09 10:46:53.669 | ERROR    | __main__:<module>:8 - division by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "new.py", line 6, in <module>
    a = 1/0

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Answer (score -3):

If you can cope with the extra dependency then use twisted.log, you don't have to explicitly log errors and also it returns the entire traceback and time to the file or stream.

Comment: Perhaps `twisted` is a good recommendation, but this answer doesn't really contribute much. It doesn't say how to use `twisted.log`, nor what advantages it has over the `logging` module from the standard library, nor explain what's meant by *"you don't have to explicitly log errors"*.

Answer (score -10):

A clean way to do it is using `format_exc()` and then parse the output to get the relevant part:

```
from traceback import format_exc

try:
    1/0
except Exception:
    print 'the relevant part is: '+format_exc().split('\n')[-2]
```

Regards

Comment: Huh? Why is that *"the relevant part"*? All the `.split('\n')[-2]` does is *throw away* the line number and traceback from the result of `format_exc()` - useful information you normally want! What's more, it doesn't even do a good job of *that*; if your exception message contains a newline, then this approach will only print the final line of the exception message - meaning that you lose the exception class and most of the exception message on top of losing the traceback. -1.