# Using python's logging module to log all exceptions and errors

Tags: python, debugging

I want to check for errors in a particular background file, but the standard error stream is being controlled by the program in the foreground and the errors in the file in the question are not being displayed. I can use the `logging` module and write output to a file, though. I was wondering how I can use this to log all exceptions, errors and their tracebacks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging uncaught exceptions in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234405/logging-uncaught-exceptions-in-python)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It's probably a bad idea to log *any* exception thrown within the program, since Python uses exceptions also for normal control flow.

Therefore you should only log *uncaught* exceptions.  You can easily do this using a logger's [`exception()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception), once you have an exception object.

To handle all uncaught exceptions, you can either wrap your script's entry point in a `try...except` block, or by installing a custom exception handler by re-assigning [`sys.excepthook()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook):

```
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')
# Configure logger to write to a file...

def my_handler(type, value, tb):
    logger.exception("Uncaught exception: {0}".format(str(value)))

# Install exception handler
sys.excepthook = my_handler

# Run your main script here:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Isn't that good idea to append `sys.__excepthook__(type, value, tb)` to your `my_handler`, so it can process default actions on exception?

Comment: @Ferdinand Beyer: Neat. Having `logger.exception("Uncaught exception: {0}: {1}".format(str(value.__class__.__name__), str(value)))` gives in my case `ERROR - Uncaught exception: IndexError: list index out of range` and prints for some reason `None`. How do i also get the full traceback? `tb` seems to be a traceback object but `traceback.print_tb(tb)` also just spits out `None`.

Comment: @bioslime see [this recipe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16993115/512111) which relies on the `exc_info` kwarg to log the traceback, too. It seems to only work with `logger.error` or `logger.critical`, but not with `logger.exception`.

Comment: The above code does not work for me.  Replacing `main()` with `hello ==== "Hello"` still results in a stack trace being printed to the console.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the question and while OP might have been satisfied, people coming from google may not be. There are valid reasons to want to log **all** raised exceptions even if they were caught by something.

Comment: I prefer this answer too：http://stackoverflow.com/a/16993115/512111

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys
import logging
import traceback

# log uncaught exceptions
def log_exceptions(type, value, tb):
    for line in traceback.TracebackException(type, value, tb).format(chain=True):
        logging.exception(line)
    logging.exception(value)

    sys.__excepthook__(type, value, tb) # calls default excepthook

sys.excepthook = log_exceptions
```

Comment: this will log and then proceed as normal.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired of the main answer + [How to write to a file, using the logging Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386698/how-to-write-to-a-file-using-the-logging-python-module) + [Print original exception in excepthook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724032/print-original-exception-in-excepthook), here is how to write the full traceback into a file `test.log`, like it would be printed in the console:

```
import logging, sys, traceback
logger = logging.getLogger('logger')
fh = logging.FileHandler('test.log')
logger.addHandler(fh)
def exc_handler(exctype, value, tb):
    logger.exception(''.join(traceback.format_exception(exctype, value, tb)))
sys.excepthook = exc_handler
print("hello")
1/0
```