# python: logging - why not logging errors?

Tags: python, logging

I have this example app:

```
test.py

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename='log/application.log')

print abc
```

When I run this app "python test.py" it will raise an SyntaxError because of the print statement (python 3).

Why is that error not logged in the log-file?

Comment: Because it does not log errors automatically, if not configured to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using python's logging module to log all exceptions and errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050775/using-pythons-logging-module-to-log-all-exceptions-and-errors)

Comment: Also a syntax error might be fatal enough to prevent the execution of the whole module.

Comment: Hmm. Whats a good (and simple) solution then to log the tracebacks and exeptions on a prodction server?

Comment: You should read the comments more carefully.