# How do I trace all functions calls and args automatically?

Tags: python, debugging, trace, sys

For the purpose of building a specialized debugger for my code I would like to trace some of the functions in my code, and to log the arguments they received in each call.

I would like to be able to do this without adding line of code to each function, or even a decorator around all functions, but to set a trace around the whole run.

This is somewhat similar to what you can do with sys.settrace in the sys module:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html

except that as far as I can tell the trace doesn't include the funcions' arguments.

So i would like to write a function that looks something like this:

```
def tracing_func(func_name, args):
    if func_name in ['func', 'foo']:
         log_func_args(func_name, args)
```

where log_func_args logs it in a file for later analysis.

Then set this function to be called whenever any function in my code is called, with the functions' name and args.

Can this be done?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054179/3044673

Comment: it only seems to work for exceptions... I want to track all function calls (and their arguments!)...

Answer (score 1):

You should try [`python-hunter`](https://github.com/ionelmc/python-hunter). Can be configured in-place or magically by just setting an environment variable. Some script I just compiled from the [cookbook](https://python-hunter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html):

**`~/bin/ptrace`**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PYTHONHUNTER="Q(stdlib=False),\
 ~Q(kind='line'),\
 ~Q(filename_contains='site-packages'),\
  Q(filename_contains='$(pwd)'),\
  action=CallPrinter(force_colors=True)" \
"$@"
```

executed like this:

```bash
pip3 install --user hunter
$ ptrace ./traceme.py 
    ./traceme.py:0     call      => <module>()
    ./traceme.py:37    call         => MyClass()
    ./traceme.py:39    return       <= MyClass: None
    ./traceme.py:46    call         => main()
    ./traceme.py:43    call            => foo(arg=10)
    ./traceme.py:44    return          <= foo: '10'
10
    ./traceme.py:39    call            => my_method(self=<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f0c65646510>, arg=10, keyword=None)
    ./traceme.py:41    return          <= my_method: '10 and None'
10 and None
['./traceme.py']
    ./traceme.py:49    return       <= main: None
    ./traceme.py:52    return    <= <module>: None
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so sys.settrace does the trick pretty well:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace

and an example:

https://pymotw.com/2/sys/tracing.html

note that the function you pass to settrace has to return a reference to itself (or to another function for further tracing in that scope).