# python output uncaught exception stacktrace with timestamp

Tags: python, python-2.7, uncaught-exception

I am using websockets library in my Python project. However the websocket library is raising connection exception when I hit Ctrl+C as follows:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1073, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "client.py", line 95, in <lambda>
    self.keepAliveTimer = Timer(15, lambda: self.sendKeepAlive())
  File "client.py", line 91, in sendKeepAlive
    self.ws.send(message)
  File "/Users/username/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/websocket/_app.py", line 156, in send
    "Connection is already closed.")
WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection is already closed.
```

However, the timestamp is not getting printed. What should I do that all the uncaught exceptions are printed with timestamp on stdout?

I don't need fix for this exception as I know the reason. My query is to get this as well as other exceptions printed on stdout with the timestamp.

Comment: Please post example code that can generate this error. There's no context.

Comment: I don't want to fix this error as I know the reason. I just want it as well as all exceptions to be printed with the timestamp.

Comment: Use `logging`, catch the exception, and log it with the timestamp. Alternatively, catch the exception and print your own timestamp.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar, you can catch exception, add there timestamp and raise it.

Comment: @SamMorgan I can't catch all the exceptions individually. Is there generic way to log all the exceptions using logging?

Comment: @ShashwatKumar, take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054179/10824407) answer.