# Is there a builtin way to log any exception?

Tags: python, exception, logging

I wrote a decorator to log any exception a function might throw.

```
import logging

def log_exception(func):
    def func_new(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(str(e))
            raise e
    return func_new
```

It is used like this:

```
@log_exception
def divide(a, b):
    return a/b
```

For example, `divide(1, 0)` would log `'division by zero'`.

My question is whether there's a builtin or more robust way to achieve the same thing. Maybe in the `logging` or `contextlib` modules?

Comment: What is wrong with your decorator that you want to replace it?

Comment: @ScottHunter Would you recommend to implement `sum` in Python over using the builtin `sum`? I'm asking whether I reimplemented a feature I'm not aware of.

Comment: Probably a good question to ask *before* you write your own solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using python's logging module to log all exceptions and errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8050775/6045800)

Comment: @ScottHunter it's just a handful of lines to show what I want, it took a minute

Comment: "Maybe in the logging or contextlib modules?" Well, did you try reading the documentation for those modules? Or the [logging module cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook)?

Comment: The duplicate is about logging all uncaught exceptions, I want to limit this to specific functions

Comment: @Tomerikoo this is close, but I want to limit the solution to specific functions

Comment: So use a decorator...