# How to save python Errors (stderr) to a log file ONLY in case errors actually happen?

Tags: python, error-handling, stderr

I have a python script that runs once a minute. For debugging, I want to create text files with errors/exceptions in case they occur. In case errors are absent, I don't want any log files.

**EDIT: I can't wrap all my code in a try/except loop, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191830/best-way-to-log-a-python-exception) doesn't help.**

First, I am saving `stderr` to .txt doing:

```
sys.stderr = open('ERRORS_%s.txt' % (infile), 'a')
with open("%s_Error_Messages.txt" % (MSKSN), "a") as myfile:
    myfile.close()
```

Second, I then try to delete empty `"%s_Error_Messages.txt" % (MSKSN)` files before any `raise SystemExit` positions since no error was raised (otherwise, the `raise SystemExit` position would not have been reached).

```
if os.path.getsize('ERRORS_%s.txt' % (infile)) == 0:
    os.remove('ERRORS_%s.txt' % (infile))
```

What I get is `WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`. I assume that this is because `stderr` is always in use by python.exe as long as the script runs.

For the first step, I also tried:

```
if sys.stderr != 0: 
   sys.stderr = open('ERRORS_%s.txt' % (infile), 'a')
```

Which does not work since sys.stderr is never 0.

**How to write sys.stderr to .txt only in case of actual errors?**

Comment: Maybe you can use the module  `logging` to help you collect error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a huge volume of error data to worry about, you can just redirect stderr into a stringIO object and then write it out (or not) depending on contents

```
import StringIO
import sys

sys.stderr = StringIO.StringIO()
# do stuff
if sys.stderr.getvalue():
   with open ("path/to/log.txt") as output:
        output.write(sys.stderr.getvalue())
```

This is a great case for a context manager that will set the replacement stderr, run your code, then reset stderr back to `sys.__stderr__` when done.

If you can't wrap the code in a try, you could also try setting this functionality using [sys.excepthook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234405/logging-uncaught-exceptions-in-python)

Comment: I can't get this work. Under #do stuff# I put something like `print(3/0)` which should output an error, but no text file is created -- which means the error didn't register with sys.stderr.

Answer (score 2):

Since the accepted answer simply doesn't actually work, Here is the solution:

You said you don't want try-except mechanism, so you can use [`sys.excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) which is called when an "unhandled" exception occurs and prints out a given traceback and exception to `sys.stderr`. Whenever you run your script, if an exception raises your program terminates(because you didn't catch it) but you can log the error in your file.

```
import sys

def myexcepthook(e_type, e_value, e_tb, org_excepthook=sys.excepthook):
    with open('errors.txt', 'a') as error_file:
        sys.stderr = error_file
        sys.stderr.write(f'--------------- Exception --------------\n')

        # Now this logs into our 'sys.stderr' which is 'error_file'.
        org_excepthook(e_type, e_value, e_tb)
        sys.stderr.write('\n')


sys.excepthook = myexcepthook

# This terminates the program here
1 / 0

print("You can see this only if an exception doesn't occur")
```

**Note** : I could directly write into the file, but I chose redirection to let original `sys.excepthook` log's it's pretty traceback. If you feel comfortable with `traceback` module you could handle it that way.

This is the output after running three times:

```
--------------- Exception --------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....", line 17, in <module>
    1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

--------------- Exception --------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....", line 17, in <module>
    1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

--------------- Exception --------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....", line 17, in <module>
    1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```