# How to get the line number on which exception or error occurred in Python?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a Django ORM query like this:

```
try:
    specialization_object = Specialization.objects.get(name="My Test Specialization")
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

When there occurs an exception then it prints "Specialization matching query does not exist.", but it does not print the line number. How can I trace the line number on which the exception or error occurred?

Comment: use `sys.exc_info()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info

Comment: But in this case the subsequent lines won't be executed. I want to handle the exception and also get the exception line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a simple solution just now:

```
import traceback
try:
    specialization_object = Specialization.objects.get(name="My Test Specialization")
except Exception as ex:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
    specialization_object = Specialization.objects.get(name="My Test Specialization")
except Exception as ex:
    logger.info(ex, exc_info=True) # exc_info will add traceback
```

further reading see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191830/how-do-i-log-a-python-error-with-debug-information)

Comment: mea culpa - just switched to logging :/

Comment: print(ex, exc_info=True) shows that exc_info is is unexpected argument here.

Comment: Or just `logger.exception(message)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't for any reason use logging, There's the standard package [traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html), and you can do something like:

```
traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
```