# How to show logging message in Python

Tags: python, error-logging

I need to show logging messages while debugging what should I do to show messages with the code like this:

```
logs.out("Here are the error messages")
logs.clear()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python logging in multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727420/using-python-logging-in-multiple-modules)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I log a Python error with debug information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191830/how-do-i-log-a-python-error-with-debug-information)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html).
Here is an example:

```
import logging

logging.debug('debug message')
logging.info('information message')
logging.warning('A warning message')
logging.error('Error Description')
logging.critical('Critical messages should be here')
```

Comment: Try something like this:
logging.basicConfig(filename='file.log', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to just output some common text for logging then you can opt in the `print()` function of Python or else of you want to log like the proper way that it should be then you can use the `logging` API provided by the Python itself as a library.

`

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', level=logging.debug)
logging.debug("Debugging")
```

`