# Log unexpected errors to file via Python logging module

Tags: python, file, logging

I've been searching the interwebs, Python's official docs, and StackOverflow for quite some time now but cannot seem to find a proper answer.

I'm following Python's official HOWTO on logging - my logger looks like this:

```
import os, logging
os.chdir("C:/Users/kerfuffle/Desktop/logtest")

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

fh = logging.FileHandler("logging.log")
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
sh = logging.StreamHandler()
sh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
sh.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(sh)

logger.debug("debug!")
logger.info("info!")
logger.warning("warning!")
```

The last 3 lines of the code work fine, we also have a proper output via the StreamHandler.

logging.log - file:

```
2020-05-27 15:41:59,586 - INFO - info!
2020-05-27 15:41:59,586 - WARNING - warning!
```

console output:

```
2020-05-27 15:41:59,584 - DEBUG - debug!
2020-05-27 15:41:59,586 - INFO - info!
2020-05-27 15:41:59,586 - WARNING - warning!
```

Now what I do not understand is the following:
If I deliberately create an error I expect it to be logged to a file. So I add the yet unknown variable "var" to my script:

```
var += 1
```

I will receive the standard error output in the console next to the StreamHandler() logging as seen above:

```
2020-05-27 15:45:37,444 - DEBUG - debug!
2020-05-27 15:45:37,445 - INFO - info!
2020-05-27 15:45:37,451 - WARNING - warning!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/kerfuffle/Desktop/logtest/file.py", line 23, in <module>
    var += 1
NameError: name 'var' is not defined
```

My logfile only shows:

```
2020-05-27 15:45:37,445 - INFO - info!
2020-05-27 15:45:37,445 - WARNING - warning!
```

I know from the tutorials that I can try to escape everything via:

```
try:
    var += 1
except Exception:
    logger.exception("You moron! Don't do that") #or
    logger.error('What a stupid error!')
```

**But how can I catch errors and write them into my log file which are not predictable or primarily not expected by the user? (=> so no try/except)**

You sometimes just don't know about errors before they are happening. For example when I have a script running via a cronjob.

Thank you for your replies! :-)

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for the following flag: [exc_info](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug)

```
try:
    var += 1
except Exception as e:
    logging.critical(e, exc_info=True)
```

This will capture the generated error message and propagates it to logging. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29556251/8140659

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This does pretty much the same as if I use "logger.exception". Maybe I formulated my question not clearly enough: I want to log errors where I don't have a "try/except"-code block.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify why you would not want to use try/except. Makes it easier to think along.

Comment: Because then I'd need to have try/except a thousand times in my code, e.g. whenever I make a DB query.

Comment: I see, well depending on how you use your code, wrapping everything in a single try/expect would be a simple way, right?

Comment: dkreeft is right - this is approach answers the question: all the code is in the try, and the except at the end captures all the fatal errors and any logging values. THANKS!