# Python: How to handle https connection refused error and write the logs in server

Tags: python-3.x, azure, rest, post, azure-functions

I am trying to handle the specific exception type for a post request but during the execution the URL is throwing the error

```
Connection refused
```

When the control reached to the code

```
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as connErr:
```

this itself throws an exception.
**"During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:"**
Where as I know print statement will not write the error to the server logs so I have to use the logger to publish the logs to the server.
So my questions are:

1. how do define exception handling in a correct way in Python.
2. Connection refused- what should I conclude by this error. Is it requires some credentials for the post request?? or that IP itself is not working??

Presently I am using Azure insight to trace the errors in the published log.

```
import requests
import logging
 
data={'number': 12524, 'type': 'issue', 'action': 'show'}

def GetPost(data):
    logging.info('-----------GetPost Function Starts Here-----------')
    try: 
        headers = {
            'user-agent': 'customize header string', 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }  
        response = requests.post('http://dummyurl.org', data= data, headers=headers, timeout=3)

        logging.info('Http received response code: ', response.status_code)
        
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as httpErr: 
        logging.error("Http Error: ", exc_info=httpErr)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as connErr:
        logging.error("Error Connecting: ", exc_info=connErr)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as timeOutErr: 
        logging.error("Timeout Error: ", exc_info=timeOutErr)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as reqErr:
        logging.error("Something Else: ", exc_info=reqErr)
    except Exception as err:
        logging.error("Other error occurred: ", exc_info=err)
        
    logging.info('-----------GetPost Function Ends Here-----------')
```

**Following is my error log taken from the Azure Insight:**

```
Error Connecting: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 353, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f53b8c1a040>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dummyip', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /test.gateway/rest/RestEndpoint (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f53b8c1a040>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/PWO_EventHubTrigger/postCall.py", line 13, in GetPost
    response = requests.post('https://dummyip:443/test.gateway/rest/RestEndpoint', data= data, headers=headers, timeout=3)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dummyip', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /test.gateway/rest/RestEndpoint (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f53b8c1a040>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I am calling **GetPost** function from the main function.
I am new to python development and trying to write a Azure functions. There are multiple similar posts are available but unable to identify the correct answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR

If you want to avoid `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred` catch the first exception from your trace.

---

Your exception handling is correct it's just that you aren't catching all of them :)

In general it is okay to do that, catch exceptions which you want to handle differently otherwise just raise/handle it commonly.

---

Your Code:

I am getting a socket error which then raises a ConnectionError, in order to fix that add the socket error as the first exception you expect:

```
def GetPost(data):
    logging.info('-----------GetPost Function Starts Here-----------')
    try: 
        headers = {
            'user-agent': 'customize header string', 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }
        response = requests.post('http://dummyurl.org', data= data, headers=headers, timeout=3)
        logging.info('Http received response code: ', response.status_code)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except socket.error as exc:
        logging.error(f"Caught exception socket.error : {exc}")
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as httpErr: 
        logging.error("Http Error: ", exc_info=httpErr)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as connErr:
        logging.error("Error Connecting: ", exc_info=connErr)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as timeOutErr: 
        logging.error("Timeout Error: ", exc_info=timeOutErr)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as reqErr:
        logging.error("Something Else: ", exc_info=reqErr)
    except Exception as err:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Something bad happened {err}") from None
    logging.info('-----------GetPost Function Ends Here-----------')


GetPost(data)
```

---

Refer: [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

> how do define exception handling in a correct way in Python.

From your description it seems your exception handling is right.

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

This problem always occur when you raise an exception or the except part has some problem in the except part.

Have you defined the 'httpErr'?

Below code seems on problem on my side:

```
try: 
    x = 2
    y = 0
    result = x / y
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    logging.error("Http Error: ", exc_info="<some info>")
```

> Connection refused- what should I conclude by this error. Is it
> requires some credentials for the post request?? or that IP itself is
> not working??

There are many possible causes of this problem. Ports, firewalls, virtual networks, ip, etc. In fact, this should be considered a completely different problem, and you need to analyze it according to the specific circumstances of the things you use.

Comment: Yes I have defined `except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as httpErr:` in code.. see my shared code..I have shared my entire function..

Comment: I have updated my question and shared logs.

Comment: @Stark Sorry, I did not notice... It looks like your code is no problem, let me take a look again.:)

Comment: Hi BZ, did you get the time to look into the issue??

Comment: @Stark Hi, Stark. I researched this yesterday, but did not find the cause of the problem. Sorry...